# Access array value from codeception object

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception, acceptance-testing, web-api-testing

I am on PHP53 so codeception 1.8

```
$response = (array)$I->grabDataFromJsonResponse("result");
\Codeception\Util\Debug::debug($response);

  Array
  (
      [*position] => 0
      [*val] => Array
          (
              [key1] => 10
              [key2] => 1
          )

      [*assocArray] => 1
  )
```

Now when I try to access the values in the array it gives me error

```
\Codeception\Util\Debug::debug($response['key1']);

[ErrorException] Undefined index: key1
```

Comment: as it should be. try `\Codeception\Util\Debug::debug($response['*val']['key1']);`

Comment: @Calimero I have tried that , says "Undefined index: *val" How can the values be fetched ?

Comment: $response[0]['*val']['key1']

Comment: @MA-Maddin Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the [**Object -> array conversion**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)

To access the protected properties (prepended with *) you have to include the sourrounding null bytes:

`$response["\0*\0val"]['key1']`

(note the double quotes)

Comment: This works! However I am also looking for an answer where I can directly get hold of an array from the response using codeception BDD style API.

Comment: Isn't grabDataFromJsonResponse doing that?

Comment: @Naktibalda grabDataFromJsonResponse is not able to take a path when arrays are involved. Any suggestions ?